# Registering commands and handlers with generic interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mediatr

I'm studying about the mediator pattern. I would like to register a handler to handle a command that has a generic type, where the type is an `IMessage`.

```cs
internal class NewEmployeeCommand<TMessage> : IRequest
    where TMessage : IMessage
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}


internal class NewEmployeeCommandHandler<TMessage>
    : IRequestHandler<NewEmployeeCommand<TMessage>>
    where TMessage : IMessage
{
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(
        NewEmployeeCommand<TMessage> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        /* DO SOMETHING */

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

When trying to send my command using `await mediator.Send(command)`, I'm getting the following exception:

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler. Register your handlers with the container.

I've already tried to configure dependency injection in several ways, but all without success:

```
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<NewEmployeeCommand<IDevMessage>>,
    NewEmployeeCommandHandler<IDevMessage>>()
services.AddTransient(
    typeof(IRequestHandler<NewEmployeeCommand<IDevMessage>>),
    typeof(NewEmployeeCommandHandler<IDevMessage>))`
```

Can anyone help me where I'm going wrong?
I'm using ASP.NET Core 6.

Comment: Based on the error message what type is command in the example given. Did you configure mediator correctly at start up

Comment: This type of open-generic type can't be regisered with MS.DI because the generic type of the implementation doesn't exactly match that of the interface, which is what MS.DI requires. Change your design or switch DI Containers.

Comment: I think you want `NewEmployeeCommandHandler<TMessage, TCommand> : IRequestHandler<TCommand> where TMessage : IMessage where TCommand : NewEmployeeCommand<TMessage>`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: That will neither work with MS.DI, as it only supports mapping the exact number and order of generic type arguments from the interface to the implementation. In your case, when you resolve an `IRequestHandler<ShipOrder>`, MS.DI will simply call `typeof(NewEmployeeCommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] { typeof(ShipOrder) })`. That, however, will fail at runtime, because `NewEmployeeCommandHandler<,>` has two generic arguments - not one.

Comment: I based my comment on the explicit generic service implementations in the question; `.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<NewEmployeeCommand<IDevMessage>>`.